# MongoDB - Dates between using $match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I try to use MongoDB `$match` to get data between 2 dates, but it turns out that the data is not returning a.k.a empty here. What it looks like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      date: {
        $gte: new Date("2022-10-23"),
        $lt: new Date("2022-10-25"),

      },

    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$title",
      title: {
        $first: "$title"
      },
      answer: {
        $push: {
          username: "$username",
          date: "$date",
          formId: "$formId",
          answer: "$answer"
        }
      }
    }
  },

])
```

Here is the data that I try to run on the Mongo playground:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/jKx_5kZnJNz

I think there is no error with my code anymore... but why it gives an empty return.

Comment: 1. The document's `date` field was a string not the Date type. You are comparing Date type with string type which will lead to incorrect output. Make sure you are comparing data with the exact type. 2. `$lt` operator will not include the document with `date: 2022-10-15`. For inclusive, you need to use `$lte` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrate the comment to the answer post for the complete explanation.

**Issue 1**

The document contains the `date` field as a string type while you are trying to compare with `Date` which leads to incorrect output.

Ensure that you are comparing both values in the exact type.

Either that *migrate* the `date` value to `Date` type or

converting the `date` field to `Date` type in the query via **`$toDate`**.

```
{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $and: [
        {
          $gte: [
            {
              $toDate: "$date"
            },
            new Date("2022-10-23")
          ]
        },
        {
          $lt: [
            {
              $toDate: "$date"
            },
            new Date("2022-10-25")
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Issue 2**

Since you are using `$lt` (`$lt: new Date("2022-10-25")`), it won't include the documents with `date: new Date("2022-10-25")`.

For inclusive end date, you shall use **`$lte`**.

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j-db91ryrkM)